# Django contact form isn't sending message content

Tags: python, django, django-forms, contact-form

My contact form sends emails to my gmail account but they never have any subject or message content. I'm not quite sure what to do next. If any more code is needed, please let me know.

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from .forms import ContactForm

try:
    from django.urls import reverse
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse  # pragma: no cover


class ContactFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    recipient_list = None
    template_name = 'contact_form/contact_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ContactFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        # ContactForm instances require instantiation with an
        # HttpRequest.
        kwargs = super(ContactFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})

        # We may also have been given a recipient list when
        # instantiated.
        if self.recipient_list is not None:
            kwargs.update({'recipient_list': self.recipient_list})
        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):

        return reverse('contact_form_sent')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template import loader


class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                           label=_(u'Your name'))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200,
                             label=_(u'Your email address'))
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,
                           label=_(u'Your message'))

    from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL

    recipient_list = [mail_tuple[1] for mail_tuple in settings.MANAGERS]

    subject_template_name = "contact_form/contact_form_subject.txt"

    template_name = 'contact_form/contact_form.txt'

    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, request=None,
                 recipient_list=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if request is None:
            raise TypeError("Keyword argument 'request' must be supplied")
        self.request = request
        if recipient_list is not None:
            self.recipient_list = recipient_list
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(data=data, files=files,
                                          *args, **kwargs)

    def message(self):
        """
        Render the body of the message to a string.
        """
        template_name = self.template_name() if \
            callable(self.template_name) \
            else self.template_name
        return loader.render_to_string(
            template_name, self.get_context(), request=self.request
        )

    def subject(self):
        """
        Render the subject of the message to a string.
        """
        template_name = self.subject_template_name() if \
            callable(self.subject_template_name) \
            else self.subject_template_name
        subject = loader.render_to_string(
            template_name, self.get_context(), request=self.request
        )
        return ''.join(subject.splitlines())

    def get_context(self):
        if not self.is_valid():
            raise ValueError(
                "Cannot generate Context from invalid contact form"
            )
        return dict(self.cleaned_data, site=get_current_site(self.request))

    def get_message_dict(self):

        if not self.is_valid():
            raise ValueError(
                "Message cannot be sent from invalid contact form"
            )
        message_dict = {}
        for message_part in ('from_email', 'message',
                             'recipient_list', 'subject'):
            attr = getattr(self, message_part)
            message_dict[message_part] = attr() if callable(attr) else attr
        return message_dict

    def save(self, fail_silently=False):
        """
        Build and send the email message.
        """
        send_mail(fail_silently=fail_silently, **self.get_message_dict())
```

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

MANAGERS = [('Manager', 'email@gmail.com')]

SITE_ID = 1
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 35000000
```

(Its saying that i have too much code and not enough details so i'm just pasting the top part so the error stops coming up)

My contact form sends emails to my gmail account but they never have any subject or message content. I'm not quite sure what to do next. If any more code is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Try add html_message to the `self.get_message_dict()` with the same value as message, and show the example of subject you generate.

Comment: are you sure that your message_dict contains all the values ?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I forgot to add {{ name }}, {{ email }} and {{ body }} to the contact_form.txt. Silly mistake.